# Linear approximation of a function to estimate values

Tags: calculus, derivatives, linear-approximation, linearization

I have a question about using the linearization of a function to estimate a given value.

> Let $f(x)=\ (5x+3)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)+\ln(2x-1)$
>
> $(a)$ Find the linearization of $f$ at $a=1$.
>
> $(b)$ Use the linear approximation to evaluate $(7.5)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\sin(\frac{9\pi}{20})+\ln(\frac{4}{5})$

Part $(a)$ was easy. I got $L(x)=\frac{29}{12}x+\frac{7}{12}$

How do I go about doing part b though? Would I just plug in $x=0.90$? Since that is the point where $5x+3=7.5,\frac{\pi}{2}x=\frac{9\pi}{20},2x-1=\frac{4}{5}$. I am not sure though. Can someone advice me if I am going about this the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you've made typos in your question

Comment: I fixed my typos.

Comment: Yes, that's what you should do.

Comment: Thank you so much!